# Connecting to oracle database using C++, the basics

Tags: c++, oracle

i have a question about the theory here, i'm just starting a project which is based on C++ applications integrating with oracle DB's, i've came to two choices, OCCI, and OCI

the OCCI is said to be aimed at C++ environment, but i was wondering, if it would be any good to use the OCI libraries from my C++ app since it is said to have better performance, or would i run into compatibility issues ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) it's a wrapper above the OCI or OCCI (not sure) will give some templates and samples to start with oracle connection in c++.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my company have about a thousand stores.

To connect Oracle / Oracle thru an MS C++ multi-thread service we perform the following tests on each thread:

- Validate DNS (gethostbyname)
- Try to open SCManager of the store (OpenSCManager)
- Verify if Oracle Service exists on the store (OpenService)
- Verify if Oracle Service is running (QueryServiceStatus)

After all, we try to connect (ado->Open)

This procedures minimize possible errors like 0xE06D7363 when connecting to a external server.